# Deployment Descriptor is not updating?

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I have installed a brand new Eclipse Java EE version. But my `web.xml` is not updating automatically as it should while creating a Servlet. Initially it just has the welcome tags, that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because you are using the Servlet 3.0 specification. `web.xml` mapping is not required for it. Check whether you have the `WebServlet` annotation in your servlets. It should do the required thing.

Servlet 3.0 uses annotations for URL mapping and not the `web.xml` servlet configuration tags.

E.g. If you are creating a Servlet called `HelloServlet` then in your `HelloServlet`, you will see the `WebServlet` annotation in it.